# Zoom OUT for fullscreen projection?

Tags: vlc, quicktime

I have a home theater setup and the beam is just barely too wide, and I'd like the video to come in a bit. I'm really surprised there is no was to zoom out, as in add black boxing to the video/squeeze it in. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm also lookin for a solution to this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With <kbd>O</kbd> (key), you set auto-scaling to "Original Size". Then, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> increase and decrease scale factor.

Take in mind that <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> don't work on "Scaled to screen" auto-scaling.

The hot keys are in this [vlc page](https://wiki.videolan.org/Hotkeys_table/).

Comment: Wow, this actually worked. There is a limit to how small it will let you scale the video, but it's good enough!

Comment: when I use Alt-o or Alt-shift-o the video is also cropped. Is there a way to watch full video in very small window?

Comment: @NiranjanKotha Alt-O and Alt-Shift-O just scales the image... it doesn't crop it, unless the size of the video is bigger than your screen. Are you sure you didn't touch the C key (cycle video crop)?

Comment: I am not sure of it but can tell me while working I want to watch videos and work and I discovered that stay on top feature of vlc useful so I reduced the window size of vlc player and then started watching videos but full video is not visible until and unless incease the size of the window (which would distract me of my work). Will Alt-shift-o or alt-o i have no effect. Can you help me

Comment: Check if "Always fit windows" is enable on Video menu.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like VLC has a zoom feature under Window > Video effects...

> **Video Magnification/Zoom In & Out**
>
> Another intriguing feature is Video Magnification. Under Geometry tab,
>   enable Magnification/Zoom option, to let it zoom in/out the video. You
>   will see a small window at top left corner with the main magnification
>   control. Fill in the triangle by clicking it to zoom into the video.
>   To view the desired video portion, move the square capturing screen
>   across the box.
>   [image: Zoom example]

Comment: Thanks, but this is the opposite that I want. I'd like to zoom OUT rather than in.

Answer (score 0):

**VLC Player - Interactive zoom / Magnify**

First go to VLC installation directory and than execute this command

vlc --video-filter "magnify" "path/to/video"